# Flutter program not showing images

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am working on project in flutter but facing issue with images. I have saved images in assets folder and provided the path in actual code but they are not visible in actual application.

ASSETS:

assets:

- assets/images/Chicken.png
- assets/images/veg.png

Application code where I've put images:

```
import '../models/category_model.dart';

final categories = [
  Category(
    numberOfItems: 43,
    imagePath: "assets/images/Chicken.png",
    categoryName: "Chicken"
  ),
  Category(
    numberOfItems: 23,
    imagePath: "assets/images/veg.png",
    categoryName: "Vegitable"
  ),
];
```

Comment: Please post the code which you tried so far, as already so many answers available, you can search for it

Comment: update with your `Catagory` class code

Comment: Please Check now

Comment: Sorry, I meant your `Catagory` model

Answer (score 0):

Add Assets path in `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
assets:
    - assets/images/
```

**Use Like:**

```
   Image.asset(
        catagories[0].imagePath, // Similar way index should be used
        height: 20,
    ),
```

Comment: i have given the path

Comment: Make sure it is properly indented, you can add a better code snippet of your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: @MoizKhalil: Please attach the image of folder structure, want to see how you created assets folder